# Promethous query

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a use case where I have a service and corresponding worker for that service.
Now I have to create grafana dashboard for those.

When I write a query. it shows both metric for service and for worker

Query : um(container_memory_usage_bytes{cluster=~"$cluster", namespace=~"$namespace", pod=~"service.*"}) by (pod)

It shows the following

- service-bhn13
- service-worker-8y7ghj
- service-notification-worker-g67y

How to change this query to only show 1st item of the list

Comment: Why don't you put `pod` into a Grafana variable?

Comment: can u help me on this

Comment: You have already managed to put `cluster` and `namespace` into variables, it is the same for `pod`. Though I would add regex to it, to remove the random characters at the end of every value. https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/filter-variables-with-regex/

Comment: but it won't solve by making it a variable..because the pods are going to be down. I can't fix it value

Comment: ah so you only want to have alive pods visible in the drop down?

Comment: yes also they are dynamic like name is not fixed

Comment: You can extract label values and use them as values in Grafana variables like so `label_values(mymetric{pod=~"service.*"}, pod)`. Then maybe use regex to group pods with the same name but different suffix. Also dont forget to set "reload on time range change".